# kthreads, workqueues, tasklets: For scheduling work on a context switch

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler, context-switch

I have a piece of work that needs to be scheduled from `context_switch` (atomic context) and maybe `scheduler_tick` (also atomic). This work function needs to operate on the calling process' `task_struct` to figure out optimal frequencies for this process and store them in the process' `task_struct` so that the next time it is being scheduled, the kernel can set the computed frequencies.

Now, changing frequencies is considered an operation that may sleep. This implies that I cannot call my work function directly from `context_switch`, but instead, have to set up either a workqueue or a tasklet.

Given how I wish to change frequencies **on** `context_switch` and how I have to create a process to do the switching for me and how this would in turn involve a context switch in itself, I'm not sure how to proceed.

To elaborate:
Lets assume 2 processes are currently running with PIDs 1000, 2000.
I'm using '->' to signal a context switch and 500 to denote the workqueue/tasklet process.

We could very well end up with something like:
1000 -> 2000 -> 500 (to set for PID 2000) -> 1000 -> 500 (to set for
PID 1000) -> 2000 -> 500 (to set for PID 2000) ... ... ..

In other words, while context switching from 1000 to 2000, `context_switch` schedules my work function to compute and/or change frequencies for the new process (2000). This might involves a context switch to my process (500). Once this process is done, we may end up switching back to 1000 which would then involve re-scheduling my process (500) and so on. The point of this example being that there are cases where we may end up switching a lot without actually doing any *real* work

I believe one kludge I could use to solve this problem would be if my process had a fixed PID after boot. Then, I could update the `context_switch` code to say:

```
if(next->pid != my_worker_pid)
    schedule_work(next);
```

Please note, that the above is just pseudo-code since I don't know which interface I should be using.

What is the right way to set up work in the kernel that should occur on context switches?